# Monster array not working the way i need it to

Tags: c++

My issue is, I would like every time a

```
Player
```

is created, for it to add 10 instances of the Monster class assigned to that player.

My work so far..

MAIN.CPP //lets user add a player.

```
if (myMenuChoice == 1) // add a player
      {
          if (numberOfPlayers>4)
          { 
              cout<<"Max of 5 players!"<<endl;
          }else{
              player[(numberOfPlayers)].addPlayer((numberOfPlayers));//create player class  
              numberOfPlayers++;

}
```

PLAYER.CPP

```
#include "main.h"

    Monster myMonsters[10]; //up to ten monsters on a team

Player::Player()
{

}

void Player::addPlayer(int x)
 {
    cout<<"added player"<<x<<endl;
    this->karma=0;
 }
```

So my thinking up to here is when ever a player is added, it should create 10 of myMonsters correct? or am i declaring it wrong?
Thus if i create player[1] , i should now have player1.myMonster[0] threw myMonster[9] Which would be different values from player2.myMonster[0] threw myMonster[9]

Now when i list myMonsters for a player, it gives weird output like so
I selected player1 monsters

```
1
4
2
```

I selected player2 monsters

```
5
```

in that order, when i list the monsters for player1 i get

```
5
4
2
```

it seems like its only making one myMonsters[10] and not for each class, how can i solve this?

Not sure if you need how iam adding monsters or viewing them but here it is,

in main.ccp

```
player[x].addMonster(monsterSelection);//add monster to this player class
```

player.cpp

```
void Player::addMonster(int monstername)
{
    int x=0;  //first monster
    if(this->numberOfMonsters >0)//do they have monsters all ready?
        x=this->numberOfMonsters;
    else
        this->numberOfMonsters = x;
    if (x<10)   
    {
        myMonsters[x].getNewMonster(monstername);
        this->numberOfMonsters++;
        cout<<"current number of monsters is: "<<numberOfMonsters;
    }
    else
        cout<<"sorry no more monsters for you!! 10 max"<<endl;
}
```

listing the monsters

```
player[x].listMyMonsters();
```

in player.cpp

```
void Player::listMyMonsters()
{
    int x;
    x = this->numberOfMonsters;
    cout<<"Total number of monsters: "<<numberOfMonsters<<endl;
    int monsterCount=0;
    while(x!=0)
    {   
        cout<<"Monster ";
        cout<< monsterCount ;
        cout<<":\t";
        cout<<myMonsters[monsterCount].name;
        monsterCount++;
        cout<<"\n";
        x--;
    }
}
```

---

update

---

```
if i add myMonsters in player.h class errors i get.
1>c:\documents and settings\tngmorse\desktop\test monsters\monstertest\monstertest\player.h(13) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'myMonsters'
1>c:\documents and settings\tngmorse\desktop\test monsters\monstertest\monstertest\player.h(13) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\documents and settings\tngmorse\desktop\test monsters\monstertest\monstertest\player.h(13) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

player.h

```
    enum Race {none,Living, Dead, Nature};
class Player
{
    public:
     Player();
    ~Player(){}


    int numberOfMonsters;
    int karma;
    bool myTurn;
    Race myRace;
    Monster myMonsters[10]; //up to ten monsters on a team


    void addPlayer(int x);
    void addMonster(int monstername);
    void listMyMonsters();
    Race getRace() const { return myRace; }


};
```

Comment: You declare Monster myMonsters[10]; outside of the declaration for class Player, so it is not a per-instance variable, it exists once throughout the entire program.

Comment: when i put it in the class i get alot of errors.  I can show if it would help solve this?

Comment: Post the error messages.

Comment: (Incidentally, why not use a vector of monsters instead of an array of monsters? Using vectors often simplifies logic and complexity.)

Comment: prob would be better, but new at this and never made it that far in learning yet.  I know there alike arrays, but stores data different..

Comment: Vectors are super cool, they expand and contract dynamically as you add or remove elements, you don't have to guess in advance how large it needs to be or whatever.

Comment: added errors and full player.h, maybe you can give answer of using that in an example?

Comment: Class Monster is unknown in your class Player.thats what error says. Did you include the header file of Monster class in  player file. If monster class is defined in smae file after defining Player, then you have to forward declare the Monter class

Comment: in player.cpp i include main.h,  in main.h i have include player.h and monster.h    not sure that is right, but i think that would mean monster class is in the player class?  added include "monster.h" to player.cpp just to make sure, same errors.

Comment: You are trying to do handsprings before you can crawl. Try making a `monster` class, and a `player` class with a `monster` member. *Nothing else until that much works perfectly.*

Comment: i do have a monster class and a player class, and when i add monsters it is accessing the monster class just does not display them correctly, due to the global myMonsters i assume

Comment: Add monster.h in player.h.

Comment: i belive i have, http://pastebin.com/G3z3Cst2   link to all 3 files, main.h, player.h, monster.h  and main.cpp, player.cpp, monster.cpp.. i know its a little ugly, but pretty short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Patashu pointed out.You declared `Monster myMonsters[10];` outside of the declaration for `class Player`, so it is not a per-instance variable, it exists once throughout the entire program

This is the way to make `Monster` a member variable of `Player`. Below code will compile. Add whatever other statements you need, add to code

//Player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER
#define PLAYER
#include "Monster.h"
class Player
{
      Monster M[10];
};
#endif
```

//Monster.h

```
#ifndef MONSTER
#define MONSTER

class Monster
{

};

#endif
```

//Main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN
#define MAIN

#include "Player.h"
#include "Monster.h"

#endif
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "Main.h"

int main()
{
    Player P;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: perfect,  not sure why that did not work last time. as the only things i was missing was the #ifndef player  #define player,  guess my way of includeing is messed up...